# Can I use aggregate functions and get individual results in one query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have an `apartment` table with many columns. Some apartments share `price` and `idlayout` column values. However, they still have different values for `area` (shoddy workmanship).

**I need to:**

1) Group the apartments with same `idlayout` and `price`, get their min and max `area` and count the number of apartments in each group.

2) List individual apartments for each group.

Can this be done with **one query** and should I even be trying to do so?

**What I tried:**

I got the query for the first part, but I can't come up with a way to list the apartments in the result set.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ), price, rooms, MAX( area ) AS areaMax, MIN( area ) AS areaMin
FROM apartment
GROUP BY price, layout_idlayout
ORDER BY rooms ASC, price ASC
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a JOIN:

```
SELECT apartment.*, areaMax, areaMin, cnt
FROM
  apartment INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      idlayout, price, MAX(area) AS areaMax, MIN(area) AS areaMin, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM
      apartment
    GROUP BY
      price, layout_idlayout) ap_grp
  ON apartment.idlayout=ap_grp.idlayout AND apartment.price=ap_grp.price
```

This will show all apartment data, along with the MAX, MIN and COUNT for other apartments that have the same price and idlayout.

Comment: This works (after fixing field names) and perfectly answers the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_concat` to list all values in a group:

```
SELECT  layout_idlayout
,       price
,       group_concat(name) as ListOfNames
,       MAX(area) as MaxArea
FROM    apartment
GROUP BY 
        price
,       layout_idlayout
```

Comment: This is great: gives a list of comma-separated values which can be easily parsed through. And *this is what I actually need*, even though I didn't mention it in the question (I need only numbers of the apartments, not the whole row, as I now realize!).

Comment: I am accepting @fthiella's answer because it achieved exactly what I asked for, even though it turned out to be less useful for me personally than yours.